# Endless reboot cycle on Mac after using sudo shutdown

Tags: bash, macos, sudo, reboot

Without proper verification I used the code generated by ChatGPT, thinking that I would set up my Mac for automatic rebooting every hour. The commands here are quite simple, and someone knowledgeable should understand this. I just want to know what has happened to my MacBook now after all of this because I was using it via remote access with AnyDesk, and it's not responding. Can you explain what the code did with it? The code is here:

```
nano ~/reboot_hourly.sh
```

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo shutdown -r now
```

```
chmod +x ~/reboot_hourly.sh
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.myreboot</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/your_username/reboot_hourly.sh</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>3600</integer>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.myreboot.plist
```

I did nothing because I don't have an acsess to my Mac right now, I just want an explanation of this code and is this in endless rebooting cycle right now or what?

Comment: Do not delete and repost questions literally if they have been closed. And don’t even create a new account for that. Edit and improve the question.I wrote a comment to your deleted question about issues in the code.

Comment: The platform suggested me to repost the question, sorry, I just need the explanation did this code put my PC in Endless reboot loop or not

Comment: It depends on a few  things beyond the code.